# Test a JavaScript script in a browser without creating html/javascript test files

Tags: javascript, debugging, testing, browser

I learn JavaScript and a have a lot of little pieces of JavaScript code to test.

Is there a way to do it, say, in Chrome or other browser, without writing a special temporary  .js/.html file?

Someone suggested me the chrome's console, but as I understand I can test only a line of code, like `alert('myVar has a value');`, but is not possible to test multiple lines of script, like

```
if(myVar){
  alert('myVar has a value');
}
else {
  alert('myVar does not have a value');
}
```

Also I would like to be able to run it *offline*, and be able to *paste* the js pieces of code to test.

Comment: Why is creating one or two files not simple enough?

Comment: if sites like "JSFiddle.net" exists, so probably is not so simple... and don't forget you should find them on the disk next time to edit, save them, reload the browser from cache and so on...

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Chrome's console to insert multiline statements.

Comment: @Serge it is possible to copy-paste multiline code, did you try it?

Comment: yes, i didn't know, thanks! (the word console usually is not associated in my mind with multiline commands...)

Comment: How exactly are you pasting? It's entirely possible to enter multi line scripts in the developer cancel. I do so all the time.

Answer (score 1):

it IS possible to test multiple lines of script in chromes console. Just test it.
One thing to know about the console. If you want to print a variable (like `console.log('myvar');`) then you only need to write `myvar`into the console (everything you put in there will be outputed on the console). So if you call a function without a returnvalue, u will see `undefined`in the console.

Another good way is to use tools like jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/